# Joining Tables with foreign keys and dates

Tags: sql, oracle, join

We are having two tables for two receptive branches named P and M.

[image]

I have added the sample data in the image above.

Currently my aim is to sync both tables with correct data.

Table P is considered to have the correct data.

1. As you can see record `ID=1000` in table P is matching with table M `ID=500`.
2. Record `ID=1001` in table P is matching with table M `ID=501` but table M seems to have a wrong date.
3. Record `ID=1002` in table P does not exist in Table M.

What i am trying to achieve is to get the records in Table P which are not matching with table M and records which exist in P and not in M.

To achieve this i made the below query, which will join with the `REGISTRATION_NO`,`COMMERCIAL_NO`,`SEL_DATE` and `TER_DATE`

```
SELECT P.* 
FROM  P LEFT JOIN M ON 
P.REGISTRATION_NO = M.REGISTRATION_NO
AND 
P.COMMERCIAL_NO = M.COMMERCIAL_NO
AND
P.SEL_DATE = M.SEL_DATE AND P.TER_DATE = M.TER_DATE
WHERE 
M.REGISTRATION_NO IS NULL
```

The Result For Above Query.
[image: The Result For Above Query.]

Now this result contains mismatching records with Table M and records which does not contain in Table M as well.

EXPECTED OUTPUT 
1. To get the M.`ID` of the miss-matching records In table M.
2. To get the P.* records which does not exist in the table M

[image]

Please help me enhance this query. to meet the requirement..

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE P (ID NUMBER,REGISTRATION_NO NUMBER,COMMERCIAL_NO NUMBER,SEL_DATE DATE,TER_DATE DATE);
CREATE TABLE M (ID NUMBER,REGISTRATION_NO NUMBER,COMMERCIAL_NO NUMBER,SEL_DATE DATE,TER_DATE DATE);

TRUNCATE TABLE P;
TRUNCATE TABLE M;


SELECT * FROM P;
SELECT * FROM M;

INSERT INTO HUDHAIFA.P
(ID,REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)
VALUES(1000,1, 100, '1-JAN-2012', '31-DEC-2012');

INSERT INTO HUDHAIFA.M
(ID,REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)
VALUES(500,1, 100, '1-JAN-2012', '31-DEC-2012');
-----------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO HUDHAIFA.P
(ID,REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)
VALUES(1001,1, 200, '1-JAN-2013', '31-DEC-2013');

INSERT INTO HUDHAIFA.M
(ID,REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)
VALUES(501,1, 200, '5-JAN-2013', '31-DEC-2013');
-----------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO HUDHAIFA.P
(ID,REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)
VALUES(1002,1, 100, '1-JAN-2014', '31-DEC-2014');
```

Comment: FK's are there for data consistency. Unrelated to select.

Comment: @APC M.ID will be null for records which does not exist, i need M.ID for mismatched records.

Comment: @APC expected output image added.

Comment: @APC `REGISTRATION_NO`,`COMMERCIAL_NO`,`SEL_DATE`,`TER_DATE` , i am doing a left join with M.REGISTRATION_NO IS NULL, which will bring mismatched and missing records.

Comment: @APC M.ID = 501 JOINS WITH P.ID = 1001, P.ID 1002 does not have a matching record in M table

Comment: `M.ID = 501` and `P.ID = 1002` will not join because COMMERCIAL_NO are different

Comment: @APC sorry, my mistake, its been updated now

Comment: There is a logical disconnect in your requirements. You say you need to join on four columns `(REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)` yet your desired output shows that you want to join records where one of those columns **does not match**. The question is  unanswerable until you can define more clearly what you actually want to do.

Comment: @APC okay lets say, i need to join both tables, P has the Correct data and  M has corrupted  data , how would be our approach on fixing this issue

Answer (score 1):

> "my aim is to sync both tables with correct data."

I think you can do this with a MERGE.

Assumption: some columns must be reliable. If the common key is not `ID` (clearly isn't) there must be something to join `M.ID = 501` to `P.ID = 1001`. So I'm guessing it is `(REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO)`.

It cannot be `(REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)` because the values of `SEL_DATE` are different in the given example.

Note that if

```
merge into M
    using ( select * from P ) p
    on (p.REGISTRATION_NO = M.REGISTRATION_NO
        and P.COMMERCIAL_NO = M.COMMERCIAL_NO)
when not matched then 
    insert (ID, REGISTRATION_NO, COMMERCIAL_NO, SEL_DATE, TER_DATE)
    values (P.ID, P.REGISTRATION_NO, P.COMMERCIAL_NO, P.SEL_DATE, P.TER_DATE)
when matched then 
    update 
    set M.ID = P.ID
        , M.SEL_DATE = P.SEL_DATE
        , M.TER_DATE = P.TER_DATE
/
```

Comment: `M.ID` , `P.ID` is primary key of that respective tables, we cannot take `M.ID = P.ID `

Comment: You have not defined what you mean by "sync". I took a guess. If this does not meet your requirements please edit your question to explain what you actually want.

Comment: i need to insert P record into M if , P record does not exist in M and , Update M records dates if it is mis matching with P.

Comment: That's what my code does. Except you complained about ID. Please define **exactly** what you want. Seriously, I am doing my best to help but you are really making it hard.

Comment: its difficult to explain the whole scenario in text, sorry,  we cannot join both tables with only `p.REGISTRATION_NO = M.REGISTRATION_NO
        and P.COMMERCIAL_NO = M.COMMERCIAL_NO` because there can be duplicate `p.REGISTRATION_NO,M.COMMERCIAL_NO ` , uniqueness is defined by all 4 columns . sorry again. if i am not clear enough. thanks for the effort

Comment: i'd rather stick with a select first, because i need to be 100% sure before running this.